# Cannot Resolve symbol 'RelativeLayout'

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a simple JFrame and there is no way to make any of several Java IDE to recognize the Class RelativeLayout. I already reinstalled the java JDK but no changes. Any help is appreciated. Any other symbol/class from swing works without problem.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * Created by Yann on 21/09/2016.
 */

public class MainWindow extends JFrame{

    private int dimX;
    private int dimY;

    private JPanel left_side;
    private JPanel center;
    private JPanel right_side;

    public MainWindow(){

    }

    public void initComponents(){


        RelativeLayout  layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

        this.getContentPane().setLayout(layout);

        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("MP4Tagger");
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(this.dimX, this.dimY));
        this.setSize(new Dimension((int)dim.getWidth(),(int)dim.getHeight()));

        this.setLocation(dim.width/2-this.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-this.getSize().height/2);
    }



}
```

Comment: Swing doesn't feature a `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: So what does? I don't remember another component library than swing?

Comment: The only Java `RelativeLayout` I know of is in Android.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, i finally solved this with a GridBagLayout.